# Javascript fetch api

Tags: javascript, fetch

i'm trying to assign the variable **countries** to the response of the fetch api but when i print out countries i get **undefined** ? can anyone explain to me why ? and a solution if it is possible.

```
async function getCountries(url) {
    const data = await fetch(url);
    const response = await data.json();
    return response;
}

let countries;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    getCountries('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
    .then(res => countries = res)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

})

console.log(countries);
```

Comment: You are not awaiting the getCountries call, so getCountries() still being executed while you are already printing the value of `countries`. You can fix it by either putting the code you want to execute upon completion of getCountries() inside the `then` block, or `await`ing the getCountries() call.

Comment: Besides that, the `DOMContentLoaded` event might be executed later than your console log, since it takes some time for the content to be done loading.

Comment: @nbokmans awaiting the fetch call ? what do you mean by that ?

Comment: You can await like so: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => { let countries = await getCountries('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all');
console.log(countries);
});`

Comment: @nbokmans thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getCountries(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        fetch(url).then(res => {
            //You can parse the countries from the api response here and return to the 
            //event listener function from here using the resolve methood call parameter
            resolve(res);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    })
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    getCountries('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
    .then(res => {
        //the returned value after api call and parsing will be available here in res
    })
})
```

Or if you dont want another function for this one you can directly get it using the following way,

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let countries;
    fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
    .then(res => {
        //the returned value after api call and parsing out the countries hereit self
        countries = res.data.countries;
    })
})
```